# Error when install package dplyr in R. Error in install.packages : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

I tried to install package dplyr but it always show the error:

```
Error in install.packages : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is the console history:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
also installing the dependency ‘BH’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/BH_1.60.0-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 15529281 bytes (14.8 MB)
downloaded 14.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/dplyr_0.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2409178 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

Error in install.packages : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1433

Comment: Are you doing this in RStudio? If so, I would recommend starting a fresh session. Many packages require you to do the same to install them.

Comment: What version of R? Can you try `options(error = recover)` to see what line in `install.packages` is failing?

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem in R for Windows 3.4

1. Go to the CRAN webpage and download and install the [R 3.4.0 Patched Build for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rtest.html)
2. Run Rstudio as administrator.
3. Install the package as usual.

Comment: As mentioned the github thread commented by Sumedh above, this error was caused by the library in `file.mtime` being used by another process, thus returning NA instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit weird, but it worked for me.

Just closing the installed packages `win-library` folder while installing package resolved the mentioned error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in R3.4 version, 
it was solved by using

```
install.packages("tidyverse",dependencies = TRUE,repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing my repository, and .libPaths variable, those didn't work. Simply rebooting my windows machine did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where my `rsession.exe` was essentially being blocked by my Advanced System Care software from accessing this file `index.html`. When I clicked on `index.html`, I wasn't sent to any particular file just the base [This PC] folder home page on Windows 10. The error you had was present for me throughout 3.4.3, 3.4.3patched, and 3.2, so it was probably a problem I was dealing with that transcended the versions themselves.

I don't know why exactly the access was really needed, but allowing it got rid of the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling my Avast antivirus for 10 minutes while the package was installed resolved my proble.

Answer (score 0):

Like @minette-van-zyl, this issue disappear when I disabled Avast (don't know why, though).